# Confidence Interval of Slope of the Regression

Tags: regression, self-study

The question is

> 1. A research team collected data on  participants in a longitudinal study. They observed that the average extent of rebellious symptoms observed at age 12 was 10.54, with an observed standard deviation of 3.42 . They observed that the average measure of aggression at age 8 was 3.54, with an observed standard deviation of 0.64 . The Pearson product moment correlation coefficient between the two variables was 0.32. The research team seeks to estimate the regression of extent of rebellious symptoms at age 12 on aggression at age 8.
>
> a)Find the estimated regression equation of extent of rebellious symptoms on the aggression measure. Find the 95% confidence interval for the slope in this equation.

The answer given is $(1.242 , 2.18)$

In my attempt I've doubled checked all my answers so my calculations are correct, that means I'm solving it using an incorrect approach.

I first found $m$, the slope of the regression $m=0.32(\frac{0.64}{3.42})=0.06$

Then the $Standard \ Error \ of\beta = \sqrt(\frac{(1-0.32^2)(0.064)^2}{(452-2)(3.42)^2})=0.0084$

Final answer of $(0.0435 , 0.0765)$

Where did I go wrong, and why is this approach wrong?

Also, the solution notes that the confidence interval excludes $0$ by a wide margin, documenting that the association is significant at the $0.05$ level. What does this mean?

Comment: Reversing your variables seems like it might match the given solution. I.e. flip the standard deviations.